# Symfony validate single property

Tags: validation, symfony-3.3

Can the symfony validator validate a single property of a deeply nested object, eg;

$this->validator->validateProperty($object, 'person.addressHistory[2].town');

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is not yet possible. However you can use the property accessor to get your value and pass it to the validator.

I've test this

**Author.php**

```
/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Length(min="10", max="255")
 */
private $firstname;
```

**Controller.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Author;
use App\Entity\Book;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface;

/**
 * @Route("/validator")
 */
class ValidatorController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var ValidatorInterface
     */
    private $validator;

    public function __construct(ValidatorInterface $validator)
    {
        $this->validator = $validator;
    }

    /**
     * @Route(name="app_validator_index", path="/")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $author = new Author();
        $author->setFirstname('too short');
        $book = new Book();
        $book->setAuthor($author);

        $pa = new PropertyAccessor();

        dump($this->validator->validateProperty($author, 'firstname')); // invalid
        dump($this->validator->validateProperty($book, 'author.firstname')); // valid
        dump($this->validator->validate($pa->getValue($book, 'author'))); // invalid
        dump($this->validator->validateProperty($pa->getValue($book, 'author'), 'firstname')); // invalid

    }
}
```